# Can't Run server with Rails 4.2.4.rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

This is sort of related to my other question listed here, but those solutions didn't work for me so I created a new rails app, but I got the same error, which I've listed below.

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-08-29 16:26:01 -0400

NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator):
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:3:in `<module:Validations>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:90:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/base.rb:294:in `<class:Base>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/base.rb:269:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

And here is the `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4.rc1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# 
gem 'brakeman', '~> 3.0.5'

gem 'dawnscanner', '~> 1.3.5'

gem 'activemodel', '~> 4.2.3'
```

It's a last resort for me to regenerate all of the files from my website to a new app, but I'm not sure why it's happening with this new project. The only thing I've done is install two gems to help me with security, so maybe that's it but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems strange to be using Rails 4.2.4 (the first gem), but then use ActiveModel 4.2.3 (the last gem). You usually get ActiveModel from the rails gem. Why do you add the 4.2.3 version? That sounds like a reasonable cause for a problem like this.

Comment: @SunilD.I can't remember the exact reason but I know that was one of the suggestions I read before, but if I comment out the gem, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the problem. I made a new app, without the two gems, and it worked. I went to my app and took out one of the gems (`dawnscanner`) and it worked.